# php date interval/date period not behaving as expected

Tags: php, date, dateinterval

After doing some research into Dateperiod, it turns out it by default excludes the enddate, even though it doesn't explicitly state that anywhere in the PHP manual. I also didn't notice any option for including it. The only option there seems to be is the option to exclude the start date. Has anyone else run across this?

Comment: I get that on my PHP 5.3 as well. Probably dateperiod is doing `< $end_date` instead of `<= $end_date` internally, so the end_date is actually excluded from the coverage period.

Comment: what is `$event_id`? what is `$data`?

Comment: why not use strtotime? `strtotime($end_date)-strtotime($start_date)` returns the number of seconds ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you forgot the time

```
  $start_date = '02/28/2012 00:00:00';
  $end_date = '02/29/2012 23:59:59';
  $intrDate = '1D';

  $start = new \DateTime($start_date);
  $end = new \DateTime($end_date);
  $interval = new \DateInterval('P'.$intrDate);
  $period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

  print_r($start_date);
  print_r($end_date);
  print_r($period);

  foreach ($period as $day) {
          $dates[] = array(
              'eventID' => $event_id, 
              'date' => $day->format('Y-m-d'), 
              'max' => $data['numAttending']);
      }

  print_r($dates);
  exit;
```

this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [eventID] => 
            [date] => 2012-02-28
            [max] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [eventID] => 
            [date] => 2012-02-29
            [max] => 
        )

)
```

without the time, you will get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [eventID] => 
            [date] => 2012-02-28
            [max] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: oh wow, I didn't think of using time. Thanks a lot. I'll go try that now.

Comment: yup that worked like a charm, thanks. I don't see why there isn't a boolean for exclude end date, seems like it would make more sense than by default not including the end date if you don't specify a time. Or is it because when the date object of the end date is instantiated it gives a time of 00:00:00, which is midnight so before the day begins?

Comment: i know, but I guess that is not how it works. well you can exclude it yes it should be 00:00:00 instead not, 23:59:59

Answer (score 0):

[php.net quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> L - Whether it's a leap year